# Netstat shows Time_Wait in MySQL Master to master replication

Tags: replication, telnet, netstat, master-master

During my master to master replication, I got a problem on telnet. After fixing it also my replication on both side doesn't work. Master 2 replicates all the database of Master 1 but Master 1 is unable to replicate it. When I see "netstat" command on Master 2, it shows Time_wait.

```
C:\Users\xxxx>netstat

Active Connections

  Proto  Local Address          Foreign Address        State
  TCP    Master 2:3306        Master 1:55907      TIME_WAIT
  TCP    Master 2:3306        Master 1:55908      TIME_WAIT
  TCP    Master 2:3306        Master 1:55909      TIME_WAIT
  TCP    Master 2:3389        xxxxx:50189         ESTABLISHED
  TCP    Master 2:38690       Master 1:3306       ESTABLISHED"
```

What could be the possible solution. I am working on replication from past 2 weeks, and I am in serious trouble. Please hel pme

Comment: Is anything displaying in the MySQL logs? Please post.

Comment: If you don't mind, then you tell me where could I find MYSQL logs. In my UI of MYSQL , it says like this :
your current log destination is set to file. for logs to be viewed within workbench they mus tbe configured to be sent to table. this option is only available in mysql version 5.1 and newer.

Comment: You'd have to login to the server and view the my.cnf for to know the absolute path to the logs. Typically on a Linux server it is in /var/log/mysql/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved my problem. Actually my password of replication was different and during configuration I put the same password on both end. Later on checking my master.config I found the problem and it is working fine now :). Thank you for your support.